# Как разлогинить пользователя сразу после того, как администратор заблокировал его?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Возник вопрос: как разлогинить авторизованного пользователя, если его заблокировал админ во время сессии, чтобы он не мог попасть на другие веб-страницы?

Answer (score 3):

Удалить запись о сессии данного пользователя из базы данных, где они расположены. Таким образом при обращении к новой странице, при сверке *сессии пользователя*, которая хранится в его cookies обзорщика, с тем что хранится в БД, сервер поймёт, что такой сессии нет и откажет в доступе.